# Accessing variables from within jQuery Document Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

I have a simple thing like this:

```
function init() {
    var $something = 'something';
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   init();
   alert($something);
}
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't, console says that $something is not defined. What's the issue?
Many thanks!

Comment: Vars declared with `var` will be local to the closure in which they are declared. As you've found, this means, therefore, that outside of that closure they are not reachable.

Comment: you must declare it globally, i.e. out side of function

Comment: Scope of `$something` is limited to inside `init()` function only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$something is defined within the scope of the function 'init' so you will only ever be able to access it from within that function as it is. If you wanted to get a value back, you could return it, like so:

```
function init() {
    var $something = 'something';
    return $something;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var $something = init();
   alert($something);
}
```

Notice that both those variables have the same name (normally a bad idea). They are each defined within their own scope, and thus they are totally different variables.

An alternate pattern might be to wrap the entire thing and use that scope, like so:

```
(function () {
    var $something;

    function init() {
        $something = 'something';
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        init();
        alert($something);
    }
})();
```

That way you have a single variable, but you avoid polluting the global namespace.

Edit:

In response to your comment, the above could be written like:

```
var newscope = function () {
    var $something;

    function init() {
        $something = 'something';
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        init();
        alert($something);
    }
}
newscope();
```

But I have defined the function AND called it at basically the same time without having to give it a name.

Comment: When I "wrap the entire thing" what am I actually doing exactly? Thanks!

Comment: You are creating a new, anonymous scope. All variables defined within that new scope will be accessible to anything else within that scope, but nothing outside of the scope will be able to access it.

Comment: @Akmur I have updated my answer with a bit of clarification. The pattern (with the anonymous function) is a pretty common pattern and it's good to familiarize yourself with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a scoping issue.

`$something` is defined within the scope of the `init()` function, and therefore, it will be disposed of when the `init()` function completes.

Answer (score 0):

Vars declared with var will be local to the closure in which they are declared. As you've found, this means, therefore, that outside of that closure they are not reachable.

There's many ways round this and each means a different design pattern. Here's one pattern you could use:

```
({
    init: function() {
        this.something = 'hello';
        jQuery(function() { this.dom_ready(); }.bind(this));
    },
    dom_ready: function() {
        //DOM code here
        alert(this.something); //hello
    }
}).init();
```

Here I declare several methods of an object, or namespace. Since they belong to, and are called in the context of, this one object, they communicate between one another with properties rather than variables.

Variables are thus demoted to being useful only within (but never outside of) the closure in which they are declared.

One advantage of this pattern is that you can separate any code that needs to wait for the DOM to be ready from any code that doesn't. This is achieved by having a dedicated `dom_ready` method.